# Focused text fields on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, input

I have a text field, that when the user selects it in a mobile browser, it gets highlighted.
[image: The black bordered square is the text field when it's on focus]

I haven't found any way to remove this (border, outline, background-color). It's different between browsers/mobiles, too. Some seem to have box-shadow etc.
Is there even a way to do this?

Comment: did you try focus, :focus {
    outline: 0;
} http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Comment: I've tried input, input:focus, input:active all with !important on border, outline etc.

Comment: can u post your code with css and html

Answer (score 0):

now used to this css

```
input:focus, input:hover{
outline:0;
border:0
}
```

Comment: Does not override the default. And there isn't really any hover on touch devices.

Comment: I doubt my own styling matter, the simplest input would still be styled when it's focused on a mobile device.